# How to hide a template list from templated class using type alias

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates

(This is for C++11)

I'm trying to hide the template list of a templated class using a type alias, so I can make the code more readable. But it is not working and I'm not even sure if that is possible to do.

My code looks something like this:

```
template<
    class A,
    class B,
    ...
    class Z>
class Class1
{
    A objA;
    B objB;
    ...
    Z objZ;
};


// Define an alias for Class1 to hide all its template parameters
// in a way that is re-usable from other classes
typedef typename Class1<class A, class B, ..., class Z> Type_Class1


template<
    class A,
    class B,
    ...
    class Z>
class Class2
{
    // Create an obj of Class1, 
    Type_Class1 class1Obj;

    ...
}

...

template<
    class A,
    class B,
    ...
    class Z>
class ClassN
{
    // Create an obj of Class1
    Type_Class1 class1Obj;

    ...
}
```

My intention is:

1. Save the lines specifying all the template parameters everytime I create an obj of Class1
2. Avoid specifying an alias type in every class where I want to create an obj of Class1

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type do you expect `Type_Class1` to be in your example?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
using Type_Class1 = Class1<A, B, ..., Z>;
```

Note that with `using` or `typedef` you'd do `Class1<A,...>` rather than `Class<class A,...>`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do doesn't work.

If I understand correctly, you want `Type_Class1` inside the class definitions to be the same as `Type_Class1<A, ..., Z>` would be, meaning that the template arguments are the same types as the class template parameters.

This is only possible in side the class itself:

```
template<
    class A,
    class B,
    ...
    class Z>
class Class2
{
    using Type_Class1 = Class1<A, ..., Z>;

    // Create an obj of Class1, 
    Type_Class1 class1Obj;

    ...
};
```

You cannot do it outside the class, because that is outside the scope of the parameters on which you want to make the type dependent.

---

What you have written has completely different behavior. The `class` keyword when used in a template argument list, rather than in a template definition's parameter list, has completely different meaning and unusual behavior that you probably don't want.

It is a so-called *elaborated type specifier* and has the effect of declaring new classes of the given names in the enclosing namespace scope (if there isn't already a class type of that name that can be found by name lookup).

Your `Type_Class1` will be `Class1` with template arguments equal to these classes, not the template parameters of the class in which you use `Type_Class1`.